Springboot Unleash Toggle is not pick the new implementation
I am trying to integrate unleash using springboot-unleash-starter.
public interface FeatureService {
@Toggle(name="isServiceEnabled", alterBean="newFeatureService")
String testMe();
}

Implementation 1
public class OldFeatureService implements FeatureService{
    @Override
    public String testMe() {
        return "Hello from OldFeatureService";
    }
}

Implementation 2
public class NewFeatureService implements FeatureService{
    @Override
    public String testMe() {
        return "Hello from NewFeatureService";
    }
}

Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestUnleashController {
    private final Unleash unleash;
       private final FeatureService featureService;

    public TestUnleashController(Unleash unleash, @Qualifier("oldFeatureService") FeatureService featureService) {
        this.unleash = unleash;
        this.featureService = featureService;
    }


    @GetMapping("/unleash")
    public String getUnleash() {
        System.out.println("Flag status:: " + unleash.isEnabled("isServiceEnabled"));
        return this.featureService.testMe();
    }
}

Console output

Flag status:: true

But the response is

Hello from OldFeatureService

Though I am able to reach unleash and get the flag status as True, I am not able to switch to the new bean. Please help.
